# GM:Studio - *.ini files doesn't load/save

Tags: file, storage, ini, game-maker

So i'm trying to make a configuration for my app, although it doesn't seem to load or save anything from/in it.
Here's the code upon creation:

```
ini_open(working_directory + "\properties.ini");
 global.width = ini_read_real('screen','width',640);
 global.height = ini_read_real('screen','height',480);
ini_close();
```

Here's the ini file:

```
[screen]
width = 1280
height = 1024
```

when i return global.width and global.height values they're still 640;480 but not as stated in the ini file, which means it doesn't even load values from the file. I was wondering, maybe I need to compile the executable and then run it as administrator, but I doubt that there could be a problem with permissions. I also added properties.ini file to "Included Files" folder so it would come with compiled exe.

Comment: First of all: what gamemaker version.. Secondly (for GM:studio) how are you testing this? Know that GM:studio completely redid the file handling.

Comment: For GMS: add file to included files (without folders) and use only file name, without path, like `ini_open("properties.ini")`

Answer (score 0):

This seems weird, but now it works. Actually the *.ini file isn't saved the same place where exe is. I just found out that it saves everything in %localappdata%// . Also it looks to be working better without dir shortcut "working_directory". So thanks, anyway